# C# sql command can not search the Total Cost

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, sum, between

I am designing a form to show the total cost on the listbox. I find that
there is a error when I try to run this command

my purpose is show the courseID , numberOfStudent and the Total cost(the sum of column "operatingCost" and column"materialFee")

I want to search the TotalCost between two value.(the value of "price1" textbox and "price2" textbox) for example search all the totalCost between 700 and 1000

but after running the command there is an error shown on the message box

the error message is about
 ErrorSystem.Date.OleDB.OleDbExceptionError(0x80040E14) select query Operator
sum(operatingCost + materialFee) >='700' andd <='1000'  missing Operator

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select courseId ,numOfStudent,sum( operatingCost + materialFee) AS Total_Cost from course group by courseId , numOfStudent having sum(operatingCost + materialFee) >= '" + price1.Text + "' and =<'" + price2.Text + "'", connection);
```

Where is my problem?Can somebody tell me please?

Comment: You don't need single quotes. And are you sure you don't wanna use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`? Also learn [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: Use between instead of `>=` and `<=`

Comment: I solved the problem ty

Answer (score 2):

There is an error on your SQL. The correct use:

```
having sum(operatingCost + materialFee) between x and y
```

or

```
having sum(operatingCost + materialFee) >= x and sum(operatingCost + materialFee) <= y
```

---

Sources:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: I change it to between format but there is a new error the error message is 
OleDbException (0x80040e07): Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: Convert your parameters (price1 and price2) to the same data type of operating Cost/materialFee (I wish that it is decimal). Result: [...] between CONVERT(x, DECIMAL(10,2)) and CONVERT(y, DECIMAL(10,2))

Answer (score 1):

```
  "... having sum(operatingCost + materialFee) between " + price1.Text + " and " + price2.Text, connection);
```

unquoted

Comment: it helped me to solve another error(0x80040e07) thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Remember for every And condition, it's a new condition. therefore, you will need to define the column again with the your condition.

Example:
SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE **Price** >='2'and **Price** <='10'

you should use `Total_Cost` instead of

> sum(operatingCost + materialFee)